# Laravel blade.php use JavaScript compiled by mix to app.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade, laravel-mix

I'd like to use a JavaScript function in my blade.php file. I created the xyz.js file with a very simple function

```
function picture(soemthing){
    document.getElementById('idXYZ').src = "example.com";
}
```

Then I added this file to the webpack.mix.js config:

```
mix.js(['resources/assets/js/app.js', 'resources/assets/js/xyz.js'], 'public/js')
.sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

and run: npm run dev. So far so good, npm compiled my script and the **picture** function was included in the app.js file. Now I'd like to add a form in blade.php and call the **picture** function on click. I created the following blade.php file:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <form>
        Enter url: <input type="text" id="someID">
        <input type="button" onclick="picture($('#someID').val())" value="Click"/>
    </form>
</div>
<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
@endsection
```

And here I got really lost (btw: I was always the backend guy). On page reload browser displays

*[Vue warn]: Error compiling template: Templates should only be responsible for mapping the state to the UI. Avoid placing tags with side-effects in your templates, such as , as they will not be parsed.*

And when I click the button I have

*Error new:76 Uncaught ReferenceError: xyz is not defined*

I understand that the first errors says that the app.js file was not loaded and that's the reason why **picture** is not found. How should I include app.js or any other compiled by mix JavaScript file? Is it really the   tag causing this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're getting the error because you're placing a new script tag inside of the vue.js application div.

If you're opening your layout file `app.blade.php` there is a div with `id="app"` and inside it you're having your content section yield. Side-effect means that you shouldn't load a new script inside a Vue.js template.

The script should be in your layout at the end of the body tag. Also the script tag should look like this:
`<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>`

Then your script should be available. But I would have a look at Vue.js and how you're handling click events there. [click handler docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html)

Comment: I have the exact <script> tag which you mentioned in the app.blade.php file just before </body> tag but the function is still not found.

Comment: The app.js is available in browser console? Maybe it is a scope issue. You could try to add your function to window object. e.g. `window.picture = picture;` just for testing.

Comment: Put it in the file where you have defined your picture function. But it would be better to use vue for event handling. Then you could attach the function like `@click.prevent="picture"` as attribute of your button and the method would be defined in `methods`. The `prevent` is doing the same as `event.preventDefault()` and is just needed if you don't like to submit the form with the click.

Comment: I've made some progress and limited my problem to a much simpler one. Since it's way different question I've created a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43504921/laravel-5-mix-app-js-file-creation

Answer (score 0):

**Try this I solved me**

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}?time={{ time() }}"></script>
```

> *" I think not all browsers support this "*