# Laravel 5 mix app.js file creation

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-mix

I created a custom JavaScript file with a simple function:

```
function picture(soemthing){
    document.getElementById('idXYZ').src = "example.com";
}
```

Then I added this file to the webpack.mix.js config:

```
mix.js(['resources/assets/js/app.js', 'resources/assets/js/xyz.js'], 'public/js')
.sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

and run: npm run dev. npm compiled my script and the picture function was included in the app.js file. Now I'd like to use the "picture" function in a blade.php but whenever I call it I get **"Uncaught ReferenceError: picture is not defined"**. I checked the page source and found that the picture function is wrapped with a different function

```
(function(module, exports) {
    function picture(soemthing) {
        document.getElementById('idXYZ').src = "example.com";
    }
})
```

Should I add some additional namespace before calling the picture function from blade.php or I have something wrong with mix configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions and classes are not exposed to the public, so all JavaScript logic should be written in the JS files. 
If you insist on writing JavaScript logic in the blade file, you could attach the function to the `window` object.

```
window.picture = function picture(soemthing){
    document.getElementById('idXYZ').src = "example.com";
}
```

...

```
window.picture()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "writing JavaScript logic in the blade file"? My intention was to simply call a JS function on button click. How else I should do this?

Comment: `$("#myNiceButton").click(function(){ picture("hello"); });`. It's generally a better idea to attach a listener in the JavaScript file, than writing an `onclick=""` in the HTML.

Comment: Sure I probably oversimplified the case. However, the question is still valid, how to access my picture function from `$("#myNiceButton").click(function(){ **here** });`

Comment: The clicked element is accessible from the `this` variable in the function() callback :-)

Comment: Yep I'm the back-end guy (for too long probably :) ). Are you saying that I can access my picture function like this `$("#myNiceButton").click(function(){ **this.picture()** });`

Comment: You should be able to just call `picture()`, but if you require access to the invoked element, you can use `this`. Fx. if the button contains a data-attribute.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142115/discussion-between-hedam-and-orim).